# Haskell - Type error in application

Tags: haskell

I have a problem writing a Haskell function. The compiler says:

> Type error in application
>
> Expression     : move (offset - 1) (saveList subList (x : xs)) xs

```
test :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
test _ [] = []
test offset (xs) = move offset [] xs
                   where
                       move offset subList (x:xs) | offset == 0 = subList ++ rotate (last (x:xs)) (x:xs)
                                                  | otherwise   = move (offset-1) (saveList subList (x:xs)) xs

                       saveList save (x:xs) = save ++ [x]

                       rotate _ [] = []
                       rotate item (x:xs) = item : (move x xs)
                
                       last (x:[]) = x
                       last (x:xs) = last xs
```

But I can't see any mistake. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `move` is supposed to be a function of three arguments, but in `rotate` you use it like this: `item : (move x xs)`.

In Haskell, `move x xs` is a valid value (it's the function obtained by currying `move` twice, first with `x` and then with `xs`), but it doesn't seem like what you want here.

When you get a confusing error message, it often helps to clarify what you mean to the compiler by adding type signatures. I added type signatures to your code like this:

```
move :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
saveList :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
rotate :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
last :: [Int] -> Int
```

GHCI then gives me the following error message, which is much more helpful about where the actual problem is:

```
foo.hs:14:52:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Int]'
           against inferred type `[Int] -> [Int]'
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `(move x xs)'
    In the expression: item : (move x xs)
    In the definition of `rotate':
        rotate item (x : xs) = item : (move x xs)
```

This error message says quite plainly that when reading `(move x xs)` on line 14, GHCI expected to find something of type `[Int]` (a list of integers), but actually found something of type `[Int] -> [Int]` (a function taking a list of integers and returning a list of integers).

Comment: Okay tank you for that. Can I also add type signatures to functions in the where clause?

Comment: @Cilenco Yes you can, just add the type signatures at the same indentation level as the functions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the function `last` exists already in `Prelude`, so you don't need to define it yourself.  Secondly, please use spaces instead of tabs.  This is about the 5th time I've said this on SO this week.  Haskell will work with tabs, but it ends up causing problems because in your editor blocks look lined up, but the parser doesn't always see it that way.  It also messes up formatting when you copy/paste into stackoverflow.

The problem I found was actually in the definition for `rotate`:

```
rotate item (x:xs) = item : move x xs
```

Here, you're only providing 2 of 3 arguments to `move`, so you're getting a type error.  I got it to compile with

```
rotate item (x:xs) = item : move x [] xs
```

But I don't know if that you're desired behavior.